# JQuery1.8.3 to JQuery 1.12.4 migrate issue

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which works fine with jQuery 1.8.3 but with jQuery 1.12.4, I got a null value:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>find demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onClick="runMe()">click me</button>

<div id="transactionTypeDiv" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
      <label for="transactionType">Transaction Type</label>
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
      <span id="transactionTypeSpan"> 
      <select id="transactionType" name="transactionType">
        <option selected="" value="blank">Select One of the Following:</option>
        <option value="Authorization">Authorization</option>
        <option value="AVS">AVS</option>
        <option value="CaptGivenAuth">Given Authorization</option>
      </select>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

<p id="output"></p>
<script>  

function runMe() {  

  $('#transactionType').val($.trim($("#transactionTypeSpan").text()));
  $('#output').text($('#transactionType').val());
  }
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

If I change  to jquery-1.12.4.js, then when you click the "click me" button, it will return null.

I tried separate the code:

```
$('#transactionType').val($.trim($("#transactionTypeSpan").text()));
```

into two lines but `$('#transacitonType').val()` is still giving me null with jquery-1.12.4 but blank with jquery-1.8.3.js

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>find demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onClick="runMe()">click me</button>

<div id="transactionTypeDiv" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
      <label for="transactionType">Transaction Type</label>
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
      <span id="transactionTypeSpan"> 
      <select id="transactionType" name="transactionType">
        <option selected="" value="blank">Select One of the Following:</option>
        <option value="Authorization">Authorization</option>
        <option value="AVS">AVS</option>
        <option value="CaptGivenAuth">Given Authorization</option>
      </select>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

<p id="output"></p>
<script>  

function runMe() {  

  $('#transactionType').val($.trim($("#transactionTypeSpan").text()));
  $('#output').text($('#transactionType').val());
  }
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `$('#transactionType').val($.trim($("#transactionTypeSpan").text()));` supposed to do? Why is your select wrapped in a span?

Comment: `console.log($.trim($("#transactionTypeSpan").text()))`

Comment: At some other places, we will append some html code segment to #transactionTypeSpan.

Comment: The code returns `Select One of the Following:
        Authorization
        AVS
        Given Authorization` so you saying it is a value.... Unclear what you are actually trying to do on that line.

Comment: I changed it to:

  $('#transactionType').val($.trim($("#transactionTypeSpan").text()));
  alert($.trim($("#transactionTypeSpan").text()));
  alert($('#transactionType').val());
  $('#output').text($('#transactionType').val());

With jquery-1.8.3, the 2nd alert() showed "blank". However, with jquery-1.12.4, it showed null

Answer (score 0):

For setting the output, you will want to use `option:selected` on your selector. I didn't follow what you were doing with the first line, so i commented it, run the snippet below.

```js
function runMe() {  
  //$('#transactionType').val($("#transactionTypeSpan").text());
  $('#output').text($('#transactionType option:selected').text());
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>find demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onClick="runMe()">click me</button>

<div id="transactionTypeDiv" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
      <label for="transactionType">Transaction Type</label>
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
      <span id="transactionTypeSpan"> 
      <select id="transactionType" name="transactionType">
        <option selected="" value="blank">Select One of the Following:</option>
        <option value="Authorization">Authorization</option>
        <option value="AVS">AVS</option>
        <option value="CaptGivenAuth">Given Authorization</option>
      </select>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

<p id="output"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry @awrfisher, the code snippet is just demonstrate the different behavior between 1.8.3 and 1.12.4. Changing the "output" is just to show the different behavior. That's not what I'm trying to do in real code.